# C#: How to structure async/await code where many requests are made for the same, slow-to-return data, which satisfies them all

Tags: .net, async-await

I am rewriting a **Windows Forms app** that has to make a call to a database server. The call can take up to 30 seconds, so I want to cache the result (it doesn't change).

How, multiple events can trigger a need for this information, depending on what other info is entered or chosen in the UI. The different UI components that might need that information aren't aware of each other.

I only want to make that DB call once. So, if you, the user, trigger that 30-second DB call (which is done asynchronously) and then 5 seconds later another part of the app discovers a need for that info, I don't want the app to fire off another DB request, just because the cache is still empty. I want it to wait the remaining 25 seconds until the info becomes available, take the cached value, and return.

But I can't quite get my head around how to structure this, both in terms of data and code.

I see this scenario as two (or more) requests, that are queued somehow, and once the first is satisfied by the DB call, the second takes the now-cached result value and returns. If, later, something else -- a third thing -- needs this information, the request will take the cached value and immediately return.

I'm wondering if there's a built-in pattern or set of data structures for doing this in .NET. I feel as if this is almost -- but not quite -- a basic `async/await` pattern, except that multiple things are awaiting the same result.

What is this pattern/architecture I'm thinking of, but can't quite visualize??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern where multiple things await the same result is just... multiple things awaiting the same task. That's it. There's no magic.

.NET's `Task` can be awaited multiple times with no issue, and store their result indefinitely (this is unlike `ValueTask`, which can only be awaited once). If you await an already completed task, it'll just return its result immediately.  So, instead of caching the result, you could just cache the task.

With that in mind, simply keep a reference to the task itself.

```
private async Task<YourDatabaseResult> RunQueryInternal()
{
    // do the actual database query here
}

private Task<YourDatabaseResult>? _task;

public Task<YourDatabaseResult> RunQuery()
{
    if (_task == null)
        _task = RunQueryInternal();
    return _task;
}
```

The first time you call the method, the query gets fired off and the task gets stored. Subsequent calls just return the same task, so everyone will await on it, and the query effectively only gets executed once.

Now, this is a bit naive, because it doesn't handle any error. But it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: It also doesn't handle any concurrency on the `if`, but I suppose in a WinForms event handler you should be safe from reentry

Comment: From the description of the problem, the operations are launched from the UI, which implies they all run on the main thread, so I assumed that concurrency wouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Caching the task generally works fine, but it's often necessary to add special handling if the task fails, to avoid caching a faulted task.